# I want to display the welcome username's message when logged in

Tags: php, mysql

My problem is that when i get `<?= $_SESSION['username'];?>` it displays only the first letter of a string and not the value of db. My problem is because i get by `$sql['username']`   but can you tell me how to do the right?

```
 <?
  // Username and password sent from form
     $myusername = $_POST['myusername'];
     $mypassword = $_POST['mypassword'];

     // Connect to DB
     $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "logmeinnow", "form");
     // Check connection
         if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
         echo "Failed to connect to DB". mysqli_error();
      }

     //Encrypt passowrd
     $encrypt_password = md5($mypassword);
     // Query from Database
     $sql    = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$myusername' and     password='$encrypt_password'";
     $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
     if(!$result) {
          die('Sql error:'.mysqli_error($con));
      }
      // Counting table row
      $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);


      //If result matched your Username and Password table row must be 1 row.
      if ($count>0) {
          // Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file index.php


           $_SESSION['is_login']   = true;
           $_SESSION['user_id']    = 0; #from db
           $_SESSION['username']   = $sql['username']; #from db
           $_SESSION['first_name'] = $sql['first_name'];
           $_SESSION['last_name']  = $sql['last_name'];

           header("Location:db.php");
           die();
           } else {
           // Redirect user to login page
           header("Location:login.php?error_id=1");
           }
   ?>
```

Comment: Eek! You’re vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)!

Comment: Where's your line fetching the record, `$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)` ?

Comment: **`session_start()`**

Comment: have you checked the value in your database? Please check it out. If it's okay please check the data type of username and how long it is. Hope this helps.

Comment: $_SESSION['username']   = $sql['username'];  where is your fetching?

Answer (score 1):

it should not be `$sql['username'];` instead I believe it should be `$result['username'];`

And one of the best way to use mysqli is

```
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$myusername' and     password='$encrypt_password'";

    if ($result = $mysqli->query($sql)) { 
        while($obj = $result->fetch_object()){ 
            $_SESSION['username'] = $obj->username; 
            $_SESSION['first_name'] = $obj->first_name; 
            $_SESSION['last_name'] = $obj->last_name; 
        } 
    } 
    $result->close(); 
    unset($obj); 
    unset($sql); 
    unset($query); 

?>
```

and should also be adding session_start() at the very top of the page

Comment: Why would the OP append the values to `$line` when he wants to add them as session values?....

Comment: `$_SESSION['username']   = $sql['username'];`
need to change .. instead use 
`$_SESSION['username']   = $result['username'];`

And also need 
`session_start()` at the top

Answer (score 0):

i think because of this

`$_SESSION['username']   = $sql['username'];`where is your fetching code?

try to do this instead

`$_SESSION['username']=$_POST['myusername'];`